# Element already defined error

Tags: xml, validation, dtd

I'm starter in xml writing and I have a problem. I have base dtd called person and i use it as entity in both trainer and company. I also have trainning root element and in this root element I either have trainer or company. When I try to validate the xml file I face an error "Element 'person' has already been declared." . How can i keep my structure as it is and validate my xml file. By the way I used entity form to reuse my person.dtd.
Thank you for your help.

This is file "person.dtd":

```
<!ELEMENT person (id, name, lastname, 
                  telNo, adress, birthday, 
                  email)>
<!ELEMENT id (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT lastname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT telNo (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT adress (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT birthday (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT email (#PCDATA)>
```

This is file "trainer.dtd":

```
<!ELEMENT trainer (trainerPerson,proficiency)> 
<!ENTITY % trainerPerson SYSTEM "person.dtd">
%trainerPerson;
<!ELEMENT proficiency (#PCDATA)>
```

This is "company.dtd":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!ELEMENT company (companyId, companyName, 
                   companyAdress, telno, contactPerson)>
<!ELEMENT companyId (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT companyName (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT companyAdress (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT telno (#PCDATA)>
<!ENTITY % contactPerson SYSTEM "person.dtd">
%contactPerson;
```

And this is the DTD for trainning information:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!ELEMENT trainning  (trainningId, cost, date, duration, 
                      trainningName, comment,
                      durationtype, (trainer|company) )>
<!ELEMENT trainningId (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT cost (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT date (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT duration (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT trainningName (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT durationtype (#PCDATA)>
<!ENTITY % trainer SYSTEM "trainer.dtd">
%trainer;
<!ENTITY % company SYSTEM "company.dtd">
%company;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the material you show is in separate files on your system and I have edited your question to make that explicit -- if I misunderstood your question, please correct the changes!

Two things are worth noting here.

First, DTD files are not XML documents, so you do not need (and should not use) an XML declaration at the beginning of a DTD file.  You should delete the first lines of company.dtd and trainning.dtd.

Second, XML DTDs must contain at most one element declaration for any given name.  Since the 'person' element is declared in person.dtd and included in trainer.dtd and company.dtd, when you embed both trainer.dtd and company.dtd in the trainning.dtd file, you cause the parser to see two declarations for 'person'.

If you really want to create three different DTDs here, with overlapping content, then the simplest solution is to make one set of  files containing *only* element declarations, and a second set of driver files which do nothing but declare parameter entities and refer to them.  So person.dtd, company.dtd, trainer.dtd, and training.dtd will all have just element declarations, and you will have three driver files, one for companies, one for trainers, and one for training, like this:

Companies.dtd contains:

```
<!ENTITY % company SYSTEM "company.dtd">
%company;
<!ENTITY % person SYSTEM "person.dtd">
%person;
```

Trainer.dtd contains:

```
<!ENTITY % trainer SYSTEM "trainer.dtd">
%trainer;
<!ENTITY % person SYSTEM "person.dtd">
%person;
```

Training.dtd contains:

```
<!ENTITY % company SYSTEM "company.dtd">
%company;
<!ENTITY % person SYSTEM "person.dtd">
%person;
<!ENTITY % trainer SYSTEM "trainer.dtd">
%trainer;
```

Even simpler, of course, would be to use a single file for everything.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, what do you mean by set of driver files?

Comment: I meant files like the Company.dtd, Trainer.dtd, Training.dtd files I show in my answer, which do nothing but embed other files (and thus can be thought of as driving the creation of the effective DTD out of the different files you have available).  These are the files you will refer to from your documents.  A document about a trainer, for example, might begin this way:  `<!DOCTYPE trainer SYSTEM "Trainer.dtd"><trainer>...` while a document about a company would begin `<!DOCTYPE company SYSTEM "Company.dtd">...`